Spring Boot Redis Caching: Nested @Cacheable Methods Not Working as Expected
I am working on a Spring Boot project that integrates Redis, Hibernate, Spring Data JPA, and MySQL. I want to cache the result of a method using the @Cacheable annotation. However, this method internally calls another method, which is also annotated with @Cacheable.
Here's an outline of the issue:
I have a method, method1, annotated with @Cacheable("method1Cache").
Inside method1, I call another method, method2, which is also annotated with @Cacheable("method2Cache").
The expected behavior is that both methods should cache their results independently.
However, it seems like method2 is not getting cached when called from within method1.
Problem: When method1 calls method2, the caching for method2 is not working as expected. If I call method2 directly, it is cached properly, but when it's called from within method1, it doesn't seem to cache the repository call to findAll().
The Hibernate SELECT query is still being executed, indicating that the cache is not being utilized.
Question: How can I ensure that both methods are cached independently, even when method2 is called within method1? Is there a specific issue with caching when one method calls another cached method that interacts with the repository?
Example Code:
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Cacheable("method1Cache")
    public String method1(Long id) {
        // Call method2 and perform logic
        List<FoodProjection> myEntity = method2(id);
        
        // Perform some logic with myEntity
        return "Relevant result";  // Return something relevant here
    }

    @Cacheable("method2Cache")
    public List<FoodProjection> method2(Long id) {
        // Call repository method to fetch data
        return myRepository.findActiveFoodsWithProjection();
    }
}

Repository Code:
@Repository
public interface FoodRepository extends JpaRepository<Food, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT f.id AS id, f.name AS name FROM Food f WHERE f.isActive = true")
    List<FoodProjection> findActiveFoodsWithProjection();

}

FoodProjection code:
public interface FoodProjection {
    
    Long getId();
    String getName();
}

